# Can I emulate x86 to run Windows 95?

Tags: emulation, windows

In a comment to [another question about Windows](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/213/141), somebody brought up a good point, Raspberry Pis have the horsepower to run older games.  It just so happens that I have a favorite older game from the win95 era that I'd like to give a go but the typical desktop hardware these days is just too advanced.

This might be a bit ingenuous, but we can [emulate ARM systems on x86](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/344/emulation-on-a-windows-pc) so is it possible to emulate x86 on ARM processors?  If the Raspberry Pi can emulate an x86 machine would there be any other complications to installing Windows 95?

Comment: A Raspberry Pi is said to be roughly equivalent to a 300 MHz Pentium II, and then it needs to emulate an x86.  To me that sounds like it will be too slow to be fun/interesting.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen is there any chance you have a link to support the 300MHz Pentium II performance?

Comment: The wording comes from the FAQ.  You might also find http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5678 interesting.

Comment: ALso note that you _can_ emulate an x86.  Question is whether you REALLY want to know if it will be fast enough to be fun.

Comment: Consider ReactOS, see [this answer](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4393/3763)

Comment: Can any of these answers be updated for modern PIs? 3 and up?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Bochs](http://bochs.sourceforge.net/) can emulate x86. ["thekeywordgeek"](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=56&t=13161) already beat me to it and has no trouble running any applications compared to DOSBox.

[DOSBox](http://www.dosbox.com/) has a limit of 64 MB. It can run [Windows 95](http://www.theosfiles.com/os_windows/ospg_w95.htm) but it's [unusable](http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/2158/196912311610341360x768s.png). After booting ,I can't even open start menu or explorer.

My `dosbox.conf`

```
memsize=64
```

..

```
[autoexec]
mount c ~
c:
imgmount a w95.img
boot w95.img
```

[Qemu](http://wiki.qemu.org/Main_Page) might be a better choice.

Comment: I'd be interested to know if anyone gets this working.

Comment: @Jivings Its alive! It took 30 mins to load on 32MB RAM.

Comment: Amazing hehehehe - got a video?

Comment: @ppumkin I'll try ... takes too long to boot.

Comment: @ppumkin I think Raspberry Pi is not fit for this. http://img201.imageshack.us/img201/3125/196912311710151360x768s.png

Comment: oh man I forgot about those lovely BSOD :-) oh well.. Nice try anyway :)

Comment: @Haskeller Oh dear. Unrelated, that background is awesome. Where's it from?

Comment: @Jivings Background http://www.wall321.com/thumbnails/detail/20120306/linux%20arch%20linux%201280x960%20wallpaper_www.wall321.com_6.jpg, really buggy Windows 95 http://img210.imageshack.us/img210/2158/196912311610341360x768s.png.

Answer (score 3):

I tried various tutorials, but the results were always too slow to be useful. (took 20 mins to boot, took 1 min to register a mouse click, 10 minutes to open Windows Explorer, etc)

Then I discovered PINN has a pre-built image that emulates Windows 98 at a usable speed. (boots in less than 3 min, mouse click register in 5 seconds, 2 min to open Windows Explorer) On a Pi 3!

(Yes, I know you asked for 95, but I hope this works for you)

Comment: Hey Botspot, can you please tell me the pinn image name?

Comment: @SuperSoda It's been a long time. I remember the name of the image included "Win 98". You won't find it in the normal OS page. I think you have to switch tabs to other OS types to find it. Sorry I can't be of more help than that.

Comment: I found the image, it's called win98-pi and you can find it in the testing category.