# Can the original StarCraft be played on LAN with a Raspberry Pi?

Tags: performance, software-installation

Update! StarCraft has been ported to ARM:

- [Reddit discussion](http://www.reddit.com/r/ReverseEngineering/comments/201a4a/starcraft_reverse_engineered_to_run_on_arm/)
- [Hacker News discussion](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=7372414)
- [Geek.com article](http://www.geek.com/games/starcraft-has-been-reverse-engineered-to-run-on-arm-1587277/)
- Download: http://repo.openpandora.org/?page=detail&app=package.starcraft

So, I've unaccepted the best answer, and the question stands as is.

---

I often meet with friends and if not more than one computer is available, we take take turns playing games. Instead, would we be able to use a Raspberry Pi with an additional monitor/keyboard/mouse to play against each other, or play on Battle.net together? If so, how would I configure this?

Minimum System Requirements from (http://gamesystemrequirements.com/):

- CPU: Pentium 90 MHz or higher
- RAM: 16 MB RAM
- VGA: DirectX-Compatible SVGA Video Card (DirectX-compatible)
- OS: Windows 95/98/NT
- HDD: 80 MB
- Sound: DirectX-compatible sound card for audio
- Network: Multiplayer System Requirements:
- 14.4Kbps Modem or Null Modem Cable
- IPX network or Battle.net (requires low-latency connection with support for 32-bit applications)
- Recommended peripherals:  Microsoft-Compatible Keyboard, Mouse

Keep in mind that the game can be installed from a USB flash drive or downloaded.

Comment: No.  The CPU cannot run x86 programs.

Comment: Yes it can be done, see the response on the pi forum. https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=96742

Answer (score 5):

No, the Raspberry Pi cannot run Starcraft.

While most desktop computers (Macs and PC's) run on Intel or AMD chips, the Pi runs on ARM. The ARM architecture is *not* compatible with Intel chips - this means that compiled code (such as [c](/questions/tagged/c)) will not be able to run on the system due to different low-level commands. This is also why you cannot install Windows or OSX on your PI.

I hope that this answered your question.

Comment: +1, although his question is referring to the original SC and not SC2

Answer (score 3):

If it requires Windows 95 or upwards, you will not be able to play it on the Pi.

Comment: SC:BW's system requirements state that you can also run it on Windows NT, which came out a few years before 95. Same issue, regardless?

Comment: Same problem - x86 architecture isn't supported on the Pi

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen and recantha -- Bump due to an ARM-compatible port of StarCraft appearing... please take another look. =)

Comment: An impressive effort.  Question is - even if this makes it run on the Pi - how well does it run.  An old PC is most likely still the best bet for a good experience.

Answer (score 2):

**Thread Ressurection!**

Actually although WINE may not be the answer, here is someone running x86 debian in QEmu on the Pi, to host a Team Speak (x86) server.  it runs at 70% CPU 24/7.

TeamSpeak (X86 on Pi)
http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=29806
[Can I emulate x86 CPU to run Teamspeak 3 server?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4296/can-i-emulate-x86-cpu-to-run-teamspeak-3-server)

Now that there is RPiX86 as well for dos games and such, you may be able to get a SC1 playing on it.
http://rpix86.patrickaalto.com/

Comment: Starcraft is a windows game, not a DOS game, so still no go there. The Pi is simply too slow to emulate windows to play StarCraft.

Answer (score 2):

Right now your best guess might be [Stratagus](https://github.com/RetroPie/RetroPie-Setup/wiki/Stratagus)

Although not perfect, it would allow you to play a version of the game:

> Stratagus is a free cross-platform real-time strategy gaming engine. Besides many open source strategy games, it supports extracted datafiles from Warcraft 1, Warcraft 2, and Starcraft 1.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it can be done, as referenced on the pi [forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=96742).

First you will need to download and install [Stratagus](https://launchpad.net/stratagus/+download) and [Stargus](https://launchpad.net/stargus/+download)

Then you need to install and unzip everything using the snippets below.

```
sudo apt-get install cmake autoconf gcc lua5.1-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev libbz2-dev libsdl1.2-dev tolua++ devscripts doxygen sharutils libmng-dev libmikmod2-dev libogg-dev libvorbis-dev libtheora-dev libsqlite3-dev libgtk2.0-dev timidity ffmpeg2theora
mkdir stratagus
cd stratagus
tar -xvfz stratagus_2.2.7.orig.tar.gz
tar -xvfz stargus_2.2.7.orig.tar.gz
cd stratagus_2.2.7.orig
mkdir build
cd build
cmake .. -DENABLE_DEV=ON
make
sudo make install
sudo make install
 [ 13%] Built target metaserver
 [ 37%] Built target png2stratagus
 [100%] Built target stratagus
 Install the project...
 -- Install configuration: ""
 -- Installing: /usr/local/games/stratagus
 -- Installing: /usr/local/bin/png2stratagus
 -- Installing: /usr/local/sbin/metaserver
 -- Installing: /usr/local/include/stratagus-game-installer.nsi
 -- Installing: /usr/local/include/stratagus-game-launcher.h
 -- Installing: /usr/local/include/stratagus-maemo-extract.h
cd /home/pi/stratagus/stargus_2.2.7.orig
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
sudo make install
```

On Raspbian Buster (with `gcc8`) the compilation of Stratagus 2.2.7 will  run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530881/facing-unable-to-find-string-literal-operator-error-when-compiling-ui-code-wit) problem. It can be fixed by adding spaces between the string literal and `_C_`.

Now copy the install.exe from your starcraft CD to /home/pi/sc/ using filezilla. If you don't have `install.exe` you can copy `stardat.mpq` and `starcraft.mpq`, and rename (or symlink) `starcraft.mpq` to `install.exe`.

Now run:

```
sudo startool /home/pi/sc /usr/share/games/stratagus/stargus
sudo ln -s /usr/local/games/stargus /usr/games/stargus
```

You will need to lower display settings to run faster or overclock or use a newer pi but experiment with your settings to see how they perform with each configuration.

Comment: On Raspbian Buster the compilation of Stratagus 2.2.7 will likely run into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30530881/facing-unable-to-find-string-literal-operator-error-when-compiling-ui-code-wit) problem. It can be fixed by adding spaces between the string literal and `_C_`

Comment: Another problem I ran into was the absence of `install.exe`, as I have a copy of the game which is already installed (the CD is long lost). This can be solved by symlinking `StarCraft.mpq` to `install.exe` before running `startool`.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of completeness, StarCraft is running fine on RPi4 using Exagear Desktop + Wine. The problem is that Exagear Desktop is not available anymore, but if you got it back then, StarCraft is a good use case. It's the only way to play the Original / Brood wars campains, as Stratagus lets you play single maps only.

Theoretically, StarCraft should also run under [`qemu-static`+`winelib`](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=226376), but I haven't tried it personally.

Also, StarCraft [has been ported to ARM](https://www.geek.com/games/starcraft-has-been-reverse-engineered-to-run-on-arm-1587277/), but AFAIK the source code is not available publicly, and the existing build is only for `armel` architecture (Raspbian is `armhf`), so tough luck.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the answer, but it is very likely possible. Just came here to say you have to compile both wine and starcraft from source. I don't know the specifics on those, but I'd just like to give hope to this really doubtful thread. Wine got downvoted because the game was thought to not be built on ARM, but if it is compiled on the Raspberry Pi along with Wine, it would most likely work. I don't know how the direct x dependency would work though.

Answer (score -1):

From the plain system requirement, you can give it a try with a decently fast SD card (or probably run it from USB a hard disk. I never tried so the experience can be bad. Also you need to make sure that the program is compiled for ARMv6 instruction set.

Answer (score -1):

if you are thinking of using the pi as a server, yes it can be done with file sharing. i used to have a zental server with a copy of minecraft. it worked just fine. you just have to file share the folder with read write permissions.

Comment: Thanks, but not as a server- as an actual machine playing the game.

Comment: This answer completely misses the point: it's StarCraft that's being discussed, not Minecraft. The first is about fighting aliens in outer space, while the latter is about building stuff out of blocks.

Answer (score -3):

You should use a program called wine, it replicates the windows api, and its free!

Comment: -1 - this won't work because the StarCraft binaries are compiled for the x86 architecture, while the Raspberry Pi is an ARM machine. WINE emulates the Windows API but does not emulate the x86 architecture

Comment: Hi there, this answer needs a lot more detail.

Comment: Hi @nc4pk, there's a few updates scattered around this thread- SC1 was ported to ARM, and x86 programs can be run on the pi. Mind taking another glance and seeing if there's a viable combination?