# Can't push qemu Debian image to Pi

Tags: qemu

I was following Keiki's [instructions](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4296/can-i-emulate-x86-cpu-to-run-teamspeak-3-server) and got stuck on the Debian image. Although I installed it successfully; I just can't see it on my hard drive (using Windows). I can check it with qemu-img but it is simply not there.

```
H:\Program Files\qemu>qemu-img info C:/debian.img
image: C:/debian.img
file format: qcow2
virtual size: 1.5G (1572864000 bytes)
disk size: 639M
cluster_size: 65536
Format specific information:
    compat: 1.1
    lazy refcounts: false
    refcount bits: 16
    corrupt: false
```

-

```
C:\>dir
 Volume in Laufwerk C: hat keine Bezeichnung.
 Volumeseriennummer: B4B0-B3B5

 Verzeichnis von C:\
29.07.2015  11:50       330.301.440 debian-8.1.0-i386-netinst.iso
21.07.2015  21:58                 0 f7d61fe20641c15cfe08fe5db177e675
31.07.2015  16:18    <DIR>          Games
21.07.2015  03:36    <DIR>          Intel
10.07.2015  13:04    <DIR>          PerfLogs
27.07.2015  21:02    <DIR>          Program Files
26.07.2015  17:05    <DIR>          Program Files (x86)
21.07.2015  03:51    <DIR>          Users
05.08.2015  10:39    <DIR>          Windows^
```

**Update**

Not even:

```
C:\>dir /A:H /B
$Recycle.Bin
bootmgr
BOOTNXT
Documents and Settings
Dokumente und Einstellungen
hiberfil.sys
MSOCache
pagefile.sys
ProgramData
Programme
Recovery
swapfile.sys
System Volume Information
```

is able to reveal it while it definetely takes up disk space as i can resize it using qemu-img

Answer (score 1):

The image is probably at `H:\Program Files\qemu\C:/debian.img` (windows path), if anywhere. I think you have mixed up the `/`s and `\`s - probably in this step:

> 3. Create image using `qemu-img.exe create -f qcow2 G:\debian.img 1500M`(smaller size should be suffient too).

Make sure you use `\`s in the path not `/`s - Windows paths use `\`, and are usually relative to the disk they are on - e.g:

**On windows systems**

Path to folder on root (C) filesystem

```
C:\Program Files\
```

Path to file on a mounted volume

```
D:\work\stuff.odt
```

Linux systems use `/`

**On Unix/Linux systems (like Raspbian)**

Path to folder on root (C) filesystem

```
/usr/share/
```

Path to file on a mounted volume

```
/run/media/WORKUSB/work/stuff.odt
```

Other things:

- `./` current directory (linux) (proably `%CD%` on Windows)
- `file:///run/media/WORKUSB/work/stuff.odt`

Comment: Already thought of that as well but nothing's in there either.

Comment: If you still have a cmd prompt in the window with qemu info, try using the [windows copy command](http://ss64.com/nt/copy.html) to copy the file to where you can see it (perhaps `copy /v C:/debian.img C:\debian.img`). The file may also be hidden

Comment: The file cannot be found in both direcotires (C:\ and qemu in \program files)