# How can I install Teamspeak 3 on Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian

I want to run TS so I can connect with my gaming community. So how can I install it on Raspbian?

I am new to Linux, and learning so if you could give me a list of commands to copy-paste, or direct me in the right direction, that would be great.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you can find an ARM version of TeamSpeak, you may be out of luck. Last time I set up a TS server, they only had pre-made binaries available.

Answer (score 1):

Raspberry Pi is based on ARM microprocessor and unfortunately there is no ARM version of ts3.

But you can use x86 emulators to run x86 apps on ARM. I know two ways

- [Step-by-Step instruction for ts3 using Qemu](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/4469/31370)
- [Step-by-Step instruction for ts3 using ExaGear Desktop](http://eltechs.com/run-teamspeak-3-server-on-raspberry-pi/)

Comment: I highly doubt this would work well enough for TS to work in a usable manner.

Comment: With Qemu TS uses 30-50% CPU in idle (no connection). With ExaGear Desktop it uses 3-4% in idle. [Screenshot](http://s22.postimg.org/wtyjjr2tt/ts3_workload.png)

Comment: yeah... I'm not sure I'd call that "usable"

Comment: Why? This is just translation from one ISA to another. It's pretty common current days: Java, Android, javascript in browser - all execute huge amount of workload in translation mode.