# Running a Teamspeak 3 Server

Tags: server

I'd love to get an extensive list of instructions or better yet a pre done download link :P

I've given it countless night with countless hours desperately trying harder and harder til I finally gave up to never touch my pi again, now it's time.

Edit: I know x86 has to be emulated but the issue is I'm struggling to even get that far with no recent download link for QEMU and no money to buy Exagear I'm out of luck as I intend to use it 24/7 even when I'm on holiday

Comment: Teamspeak does not support the RP without emulating, because teamspeak is not build for ARM

Comment: See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4296/can-i-emulate-x86-cpu-to-run-teamspeak-3-server and http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/36346/how-can-i-install-teamspeak-3-on-raspbian Is any of those a duplicate to this question?

Answer (score 1):

It's **only** possible to run this with ExaGear or QEMU eumalation at this moment.
Here are the guides:

[Run TeamSpeak 3 Server on Raspberry Pi](https://eltechs.com/run-teamspeak-3-server-on-raspberry-pi/)

[Teamspeak server on Pi](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=41&t=29806)

Comment: Issue still stands with QEMU the download link is no longer working due to the posts being a few years old

Comment: Nope. Just visit http://qemu.weilnetz.de/

Comment: I've never seen the link before, I was only able to find sourceforge with a working download and an IP which no longer worked so thanks :D