# Programming without a device

Tags: software-development, emulation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Emulation on a PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/165/emulation-on-a-pc)

How can a virtual environment be set up to program for the Raspberry Pi without using the device itself?

Comment: I do not understand the difference between this and the [previous question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/165/emulation-on-a-pc) you refer to.  Accessing the filesystem on the SD card is relatively simple compared to emulating the SoC or reimplementing its APIs

Comment: An answer to the previous question explaining how to do a software-only emulation would not be relevant.

Comment: Please see my answer to your [previous question](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/165/emulation-on-a-pc).

Comment: @Jivings your walkthrough should really be an answer to this question, while the other question would simply need instructions on how to transfer an emulated image to an SD card.

Comment: The questions are still very similar.  I think one question should be enough to cover emulation/simulation on windows/linux/mac.