# How does speed of QEMU emulation compare to a real Raspberry Pi board?

Tags: emulation

I've managed to following [Jivings answer](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/286/86) to set up QEMU on my Ubuntu machine with the default Debian image, though I have had to use `arm1136-r2` instead of `arm1176`.

What is the best way to compare the speed the emulated processor is running at?

Doing a `cat /proc/cpuinfo` gives me `BogoMIPS = 135.57`. This was on a Intel Atom @1.6 GHz, no KVM.

How does this relate to an actual Raspberry Pi?

Comment: I'm guessing you don't mean the contents of `/proc/cpuinfo` but actually the raw number of instructions per second?

Answer (score 4):

On my Pi, `cat /proc/cpuinfo` gives me:

```
pi@raspberrypi:~$ cat /proc/cpuinfo
Processor       : ARMv6-compatible processor rev 7 (v6l)
BogoMIPS        : 697.95
Features        : swp half thumb fastmult vfp edsp java tls
CPU implementer : 0x41
CPU architecture: 7
CPU variant     : 0x0
CPU part        : 0xb76
CPU revision    : 7
```

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica, which is available now for the Rpi, has a benchmarking tool.  One example is to calculate a discrete fourier transform.  I timed the operation five times each on an RPi and Qemu-RPi on a Xeon 6-core Windows 64-bit system and obtained the following:

- RPi 5.55s (0.7% variability)
- Qemu 12.9 (1.4% variability)

So it looks like the emulator is taking a roughly 50% speed hit under these conditions.

For those interested, here is the Mathematica code I ran:

```
Table[Module[{data},Timing[SeedRandom[1];data=RandomReal[{},{120000}];Do
[Fourier[data],{11}]]],{5}]
```