# Emulate the Raspberry Pi on OS X 10.10 Yosemite (Xcode 6.1.1 with Command Line Tools)

Tags: emulation, macos, qemu

I'm keen to Emulate the Raspberry Pi on **OS X 10.10 Yosemite** (**not Linux**)
(Xcode 6.1.1 with Command Line Tools)

Can anyone point the way to Emulating a Raspberry Pi ***under OS X***?

Using Homebrew or macports is fine, as is using QEMU.

Comment: Right now this is a duplicate of the question Jacobm001 references, in so far as the only emulator for the pi is QEMU, which apparently [can work on OSX](http://www.royvanrijn.com/blog/2014/06/raspberry-pi-emulation-on-os-x/). Googling "raspberry pi emulator OSX" would have revealed that, BTW.  *Search engines are your friend!*

Comment: Please note this question specifically refers to OSX not Linux

Comment: Hmm the tutorials all call for very old versions of QEMU? Some 1.1.0(but not 1.1.0-1) some 1.7.1.

Comment: The speed comparison leads me to believe most get one or twe RPi and just develop directly on the device:http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/333/how-does-speed-of-qemu-emulation-compare-to-a-real-raspberry-pi-board?rq=1