# How to emulate a Raspberry Pi on a Mac? (without assuming previous command line knowledge)

Tags: emulation

Can anyone point me a tutorial on emulation for the completely clueless person?
(To be clear: I'm willing to learn the command line stuff, I just need something that doesn't assume I know it)

I have been instructed to set up a QEMU emulation and [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/28254/emulate-the-raspberry-pi-on-os-x-10-10-yosemite-xcode-6-1-1-with-command-line-t) pointed to a [tutorial](http://www.royvanrijn.com/blog/2014/06/raspberry-pi-emulation-on-os-x/) that did not help much.

I also tried to run Q on my Mac but I don't understand a single thing...

Comment: Why no "command line stuff?" You need to use the command line to _use_ the Pi, emulated or not.

Comment: Sure, I want to learn the command line stuff. I mean at this point I have to be led by the hand as I know very little and I couldn't follow the instructions I found.

Comment: Why not get  a Pi and avoid the extra complication of virtualization.

Comment: I don't have my Pi with me right now and I would like to play with it.

Comment: Why not wait for your pi? If you insist on virtualizing, you will need to mess around with the command line. The command line is simple enough to learn if you're willing to.

Comment: I'm willing to learn! I just need a more detailed tutorial I guess.

Comment: What these gentlemen are not telling you is that they do not know how to nicely boot a pi image with qemu arm. For obvious reasons (snapshots, no need to re-image after big errors) this is something we all want to do. See http://blog.3mdeb.com/2015/12/30/emulate-rapberry-pi-2-in-qemu/ and https://blog.flexvdi.com/2015/03/17/enabling-kvm-virtualization-on-the-raspberry-pi-2/ . I needed to do this a while back, please provide feedback when you find the correct method for pi2/3.