# Emulation on a Windows PC

Tags: emulation, windows

How can I emulate the Raspberry Pi on Windows?

> Related: [Emulation on a Linux PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/165/141)

Comment: Meta discussion: http://meta.raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/122/35

Comment: Cygwin must be used to run QEMU in Windows. I don't know any other way.

Comment: @Jivings There's a(n unofficial) precompiled version - http://lassauge.free.fr/qemu/

Comment: That's what I was referring to. It requires Cygwin.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Emulation on a Linux PC](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/165/emulation-on-a-linux-pc)

Comment: Just asking, but is this not just the same as emulating Debian?

Comment: @ACarter It's not. Because Alex wants to emulate the ARM architecture, just just the OS.

Comment: I'm still disappointed with the quality of the answers here; they are either prone to link rot or don't explain what is going on.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I plan on making my answer stand alone. I'll put it on my to-do list. I see this question having a lot of value for a large audience.

Comment: thanks in advance as i am about to by raspberry pi for education purpose in rural India this emulator was the piece of software is was searching form weeks ..

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I will revisit my answer hopefully over the Holiday break.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I found a rare gem of a tutorial while trying to find updates for the [RISC OS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RISC_OS) distribution for the RPi. It goes in-depth on how to [emulate the RPi in Windows using QEMU](http://cronicasredux.blogspot.com/2011/09/installing-and-running-debian-armel-on.html). The tutorial is also generous enough to provide a link to the Win32 binary for [QEMU](http://wiki.qemu.org/). I plan on following this tutorial myself when I find the time.

Comment: Could you please expand your answer to protect against link rot? Cheers!

Comment: Of course! I'll have it done soon.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson Soon?

Comment: @Jivings I've been attacked by life which has made my schedule quite busy. It's still on my list of things to do, though! I'd normally do it at work, but I got a new job that's much more time-consuming.

Comment: Well, it's been 15 months...

Comment: @ThatBrazilianGuy I know; I'm a terrible person. It's still on my list, though, along with a couple things for AskDifferent.

Comment: It's ok, I still believe in you!

Comment: @Andrew: Soon? It's been nearly five years ...

Comment: @FighterJet Soon was probably the wrong word to use... It will get done *eventually*!

Comment: To fight against the inevitable link rot, I've put it through an archiver: http://archive.is/ZQjwB Though, I do still want to put the summary/basics into my answer.

Comment: Another archive, just in case: https://web.archive.org/web/20200725153907/http://cronicasredux.blogspot.com/2011/09/installing-and-running-debian-armel-on.html

Answer (score 13):

There is a very nice Raspberry Pi forum posting about [“Emulating Raspberry Pi in Windows the easy way”](https://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5743). Somebody already did all the work to make Raspberry Pi emulation in Windows as simple as possible. The instructions are:

1. [download a zip from SourceForge](https://sourceforge.net/projects/rpiqemuwindows/)
2. Unzip the file when it finishes downloading.
3. Inside the folder you should find a `run.bat` file which will do all the magic for you.

The zip file is literally Raspberry Pi in a zip. It contains QEMU along with the Wheezy squeeze, and the batch file that you run to start the emulation contains the exact command to start QEMU as an ARM CPU running Wheezy. This is the epitome of KISS.

It should be noted that others have downloaded and checked the files for viruses, and that the emulation has been confirmed on several versions of Windows. I can confirm the emulation works in Windows 7 Ultimate.

Bear in mind that the default keyboard layout is English GB.  If you are using an English US keyboard then there'll be some problems with the `|` character, to fix it you need to run the configure keyboard option at the `raspi-config` tool at first boot up.

Comment: I can also confirm that this way works also in Windows 10.

Answer (score 2):

You can emulate the RPi in VirtualBox with relative ease.

Here is a [thread](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=2961) with instructions. It's rather straightforward to get this up and running.

EDIT: You need to get Scratchbox and QEMU working with this as VirtualBox doens't emulate ARM out the box.

[Here](http://russelldavis.org/2012/01/28/setting-up-a-vm-for-raspberry-pi-development-using-virtualbox-scratchbox2-qemu-part-3/) are further instructions. ([Same link, from web.archive.org](https://web.archive.org/web/20130128205002/http://russelldavis.org/2012/01/28/setting-up-a-vm-for-raspberry-pi-development-using-virtualbox-scratchbox2-qemu-part-3/))

Comment: The problem with this is that it wont be ARM architecture.

Comment: Really? VirtualBox doesn't emulate that?

Comment: No, you need to use a instruction set emulator, such as QEMU.

Comment: TIL... Updated my post

Comment: Nice, you have my upvote now.

Comment: If the links die, this answer will be rather useless. Could you summarise the content?

Comment: link to instructions are dead :(

Answer (score -2):

You could easily try my Raspberry Pi simulator included with sensor, command line and file editor at iotify.io. Check out our documentation at https://docs.iotify.io/ to get started with the different projects OS and make yourself familiar with Raspberry Pi working environment.

[image: Screenshot of Raspberry Pi simulator]