# How to run Raspbian on VirtualBox?

Tags: emulation, raspbian

I have tried Debian on [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) and would like to check out Raspbian. How do I install Raspbian on VirtualBox?

Comment: Check http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/344/emulation-on-a-windows-pc and http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/165/emulation-on-a-linux-pc

Comment: @asalamon74 i'm looking for more specific answer for Raspbian OS. I tried Debian, it works but i have no idea how to do it for Raspbian.

Comment: Are you using Windows or Linux?

Comment: @AlexChamberlain i'm running Windows.

Comment: Try to read http://arstechnica.com/information-technology/2016/12/raspberry-pi-pixel-pc-download-details/ and try this one to install it virtualbox : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiM9-lxnmE0

Comment: Try this, for me works very fine :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WOxmq8K-a-k&t

Answer (score 90, accepted):

VirtualBox lets you run x86 virtual machines on an x86 processor. Raspbian is a distribution for ARM processors. Raspbian cannot run in VirtualBox.

[Raspbian is essentially Debian](http://www.raspbian.org/RaspbianFAQ#What_is_Raspbian.3F) with binaries compiled to match the Pi's processor more closely than the official Debian binaries. So if you're going to your system in a virtual machine rather than on Pi hardware, there is very little reason to run Raspbian and not Debian.

If you really want to run Raspbian in a virtual machine on your PC (again, for most purposes, you might as well run Debian x86), you need one that emulates the hardware, such as [QEmu](http://www.qemu.org/). See [Emulation on a Windows PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/344/emulation-on-a-windows-pc)

Comment: There is a very good reason to run Raspbian and not Debian, and that is to make sure that your code can compile with a ARM toolset.

Comment: @JBentley Most people cross-compile.

Comment: Another reason (the reason I came here) might be to configure your raspbian before copying on PI. I can't connect the PI to the network or screen with keyboard...

Comment: If that so, why there is a virtualbox version for DietPi... DietPi is used for RaspberryPi/ OrangePi/ etc. ?

Comment: @SidhiCiang DietPi is an operating system which has both an ARM release (that you can use on a Raspberry Pi) and an x86 release (that you can use on a PC or in VirtualBox). Raspbian only has an ARM release (it's pretty much just a rebranded Debian, so if you want to run it on a PC, just run Debian).

Comment: @Giles : what about this ? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eiM9-lxnmE0

Comment: @SidhiCiang Once again, this is about installing an x86 release of a distribution in VirtualBox. My answer is specifically about Raspbian, not about all the other Linux distributions out there.

Comment: Another usage scenario: I have several sdcard images from older pi installations. It would be nice if I could just create a Virtualbox VM and boot it off the images to see what's on them. My need for this just hasn't been urgent enough to motivate me to figure out QEmu yet :)

Comment: [try this](http://www.aoakley.com/articles/2017-07-04-raspbian-x86-virtualbox.php)

Answer (score 3):

Raspberry Pi Desktop is also available.  You can download that and run it in a virtual machine. Just go to the following link and scroll down to **Raspberry Pi Desktop (for PC and Mac)**

https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/

Just to clarify, the Raspberry Pi Desktop is compiled for x86 processors but is otherwise the same Raspberry Pi OS that you are used to. You can run it on a physical or a virtual machine.

Comment: To clarify a bit, you should mention that Raspberry Pi Desktop is compiled for x86 processors and not for ARM.