# Is it possible to install Raspbmc without a wired internet connection?

Tags: operating-systems, raspbmc

I don't have a wired internet connection and I was wondering if it would be possible to install the latest version onto the SD card?

Alternatively I tried bridging my laptop's wireless connection with its wired connection but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: Why do you need a wired internet connection? You download the image onto your laptop and clone it onto your SD card. Have I misunderstood your question?

Comment: Unless I've completely gotten the wrong end of the stick, it asks for a wired connection to update on the first boot. I thought that explained why the downloaded file was only 6MB.

Comment: O I see... I haven't actually used RaspBMC, so I don't know. Bridging the connection on your laptop sounds like a good plan.

Comment: What has a wireless connection, your laptop or your Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just use the standalone image, which does not require a network connection for installation, as all components are included in the image.

This is accessible from [the RaspBMC download page](http://www.raspbmc.com/download)

Answer (score 2):

What you could do instead of bridging the connection is to emulate the Raspberry Pi on your laptop and boot into the image. You can then update that image before flashing it to your SD card.

There are instructions on how to emulate the Raspberry Pi using Qemu in these two questions:

- [Emulation on a Linux PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/165/40)
- [Emulation on a Windows PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/344/40)

Comment: Thank you! That worked a treat! Why didn't I think of that?! Sorry it's taken me so long to try it out, just started uni and life's been very busy.

Comment: @BenElgar No worries, glad I could help :)

Comment: @BenElgar: Also, by coincidence, earlier today I was thinking of backing up and hosting my own Raspbmc system complete with plugins for a standard media centre. Do you think there would be demand for it?

Comment: Yes, though I imagine it would depend on what plugins you were including. I'm based in the UK so have BBC iPlayer and 4oD installed (which took a little fiddling) but I imagine people in different locations would have different requirements.

Comment: @BenElgar: Me too. Also TVCatchup.

Answer (score 0):

Just download the full ISO form [here.(offical downloads](http://downloads.raspberrypi.org/download.php?file=/images/raspbian/2012-09-18-wheezy-raspbian/2012-09-18-wheezy-raspbian.zip))

And burn the ISO to yur SD card (Minimum 2GB required) [Look- Here is some more help.](http://elinux.org/RPi_Easy_SD_Card_Setup)

I am not sure why and form where you got that self installing version? weird ...

Then- if you are using Windows 7 you can share your wired internet from your computer using your WiFi card in adhoc mode- (Not all WiFi supports this)

In the most extreme case- If you got an Android or iPhone- There is an option to use your 3G/HSDPA as a Hotspot for all your Wifi Devices.

But [there is also a way to share](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/12444/windows-7-share-wi-fi-internet-with-lan-users/) your Wifi via LAN (using **crossover** LAN cable from Point-to-Point!)(or a switch in the middle, using 2 cables Point-Switch-Point) But you have to set static IP's all over the place.

Comment: FYI, the OP is asking about [RASPbmc](http://www.raspbmc.com/about/) which is a minimal Linux distribution based on Debian that brings XBMC to the Raspberry Pi.