# Emulator to write a program without a physical raspberry pi device

Tags: java

I don't have a physical raspberry pi device but I want to create a program to run on it. I will eventually have that device but in the meanwhile is there an emulator which I can use to test my program.

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, I saw the suggestions which stackexchange gave back but not able to find a relevant discussion.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please check http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/165/19949 and http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/344/19949 if this answers your question.

Comment: You didn't mention your OS, but I think no matter what the answer is QEMU, which runs on Mac/Windows/Linux.