# Which is the highest version of libc6 available for Raspbian?

Tags: raspbian, packages

I am trying to install libwvstreams4.6-base offline using dpkg. I am getting a dependency error for libc6 ( >= 2.15) but I am unable to find this required version for raspbian. Currently, libc6 2.13 is installed on my RPi. Due to some reasons, I cannot connect my RPi to a WiFi or a wired ethernet and need to install wvdial and libwvstreams to enable dongle usage.
[image]

Comment: Is it possible for you to access the Rasbpian image before you flash it to an SD card?

Comment: I have downloaded the image on my x86 desktop running ubuntu 12.04. What do you want me to do with the image?

Answer (score 4):

You can use unstable packages. Just add this line to /etc/apt/sources.list:

```
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main
```

To upgrade your packages, run

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade libc6
```

Answer (score 1):

If you emulate a Raspberry Pi using QEMU ([as detailed here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/286/40)) then you can load the image and install your packages from the internet on your Ubuntu machine.

After you've installed the packages, take the modified image and flash it to SD card as normal. It will keep all the changes that you made in the emulated environment.

This is probably much easier that resolving all the package dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

The version of libc6 depends on the release of raspbian you are running, right now wheezy has 2.13-38+rpi2+deb7u10 jessie has 2.19-18+deb8u3 and stretch has 2.22-4

I would guess that your problem is you are trying to install packages intended for jessie on a wheezy system.

Answer (score 0):

Update Whizzy 1st

```
% sudo apt-get update
% sudo apt-get upgrade
% sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After that rewrite 'whizzy' to 'jessie' in whole text below.

```
% sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
% sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/collabora.list
% sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list
```

Now, we can update again as a Jessie.

```
% sudo apt-get update
% sudo apt-get upgrade
% sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

After update, reboot your RPi

```
% sudo reboot
```

Finally you can see a new version of libc6

```
$ sudo dpkg -l libc6
+++-=====
ii  libc6:armhf                2.19-18            armhf              GNU C Library: Shared libraries
```

It will took a 3HR or more....
Have fun!

Yoshi

Comment: Answering this question with "update the OS" is not appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Add unstable packages with

```
sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid main" > /etc/apt/sources.list'
```

and upgrade packages

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade libc6
```