# Problem with public keys, installing libc6

Tags: apt, packages

I'm having trouble installing a dependency on `libc6`. I'm trying to follow the solution in [this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/12573/which-is-the-highest-version-of-libc6-available-for-raspbian) but I get the following response from `sudo apt update`:

```
Hit:1 http://archive.raspberrypi.org/debian stretch InRelease
Hit:2 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian stretch InRelease                                               
Ign:3 http://apt.mopidy.com stretch InRelease                                                                  
Hit:4 http://apt.mopidy.com stretch Release                                                                
Get:5 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid InRelease [242 kB]                         
Err:5 http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid InRelease                                  
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 7638D0442B90D010 NO_PUBKEY 04EE7237B7D453EC
E: The repository 'http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian sid InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

I've tried running `gpg --keyserver keyring.debian.org --recv-keys 7638D0442B90D010` and similar with different keyservers, but none of them respond. I really don't have any idea what I'm doing: what's the problem and how do I fix it?

Comment: why are you trying to install unstable (sid)? clearly an answer from 3 years ago is no longer relevant. What do you mean by `installing a dependency on libc6`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mixed up **Raspbian** with **Debian** repositories and in addition the stable release (stretch) with the unstable release (sid). More mixing is hardly possible. This cannot work. You should edit `/etc/apt/sources.list` and use only the stable release **stretch** from the **Raspbian** repository as set by default.

Or you may try to use the testing version **buster**. Then you have to replace the version `stretch` with `buster` in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/raspi.list`. Then on a **stretch** installation do `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade`.

The unstable version **sid** is not available on the Raspbian repositories.

The link you have given to another question has some answers but no one was accepted. The whole repository is compiled against its kernel and modules. **Raspbian** has its own kernel, modules and drivers. I don't believe that it fits in all cases to the **Debian** repository.

Mixing different versions (e.g. stable with testing) is a very complicated task. The parts from the higher version also needs the libraries of the higher version and they will complain it with an error message. So you end up in an installation with mixed libraries that are also used by the programs with lower version. I haven't made good experience with this. It is the reason why **Debian** have made the [backports](https://backports.debian.org/) with new programs linked against old libraries.

Comment: `buster` was the key I needed - I've managed to fix everything now I think (although I wiped the pi and started from scratch). For what it's worth, the mixing wasn't really on my part - if you check out the question I linked, that's what the top answer there suggests. If that advice is misleading, you may want to follow it up with them.

Comment: @preferred_anon I have updated the answer with the last two paragraphs.