# Is it possible to run the raspbian based Kano OS in QEMU?

Tags: raspbian, kernel, qemu

[Kano](http://eu.kano.me/) is a real, real cool device for kids.

I wonder if I can run Kano OS in an emulator like qemu. I'd really like to check it out before buying it. After all Kano OS is just a Raspbian based OS which runs on a Raspberry Pi 2 normally as far as I understand.

I followed the [various tutorials](https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel/wiki) on how to run it under qemu (I use ubuntu) and use this command:

`$ qemu-system-arm -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb -no-reboot -serial stdio -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw" -hda Kanux-Beta-v2.2.0-jessie-release.img -kernel kernel-qemu-4.1.7-jessie`

The `Kanux-Beta-v2.2.0-jessie-release.img` is downloaded from the [Kano Website](http://www2.kano.me/downloads) (*Download the image directly* link), the `kernel-qemu-4.1.7-jessie` from the other "raspbian on qemu" [tutorial](https://github.com/dhruvvyas90/qemu-rpi-kernel).

But I always end up with a kernel panic right after booting:

[image]

After searching the web, I suppose the error is maybe because kernel and img do not fit each other. If so, where get the right kernel from?

And anyway, **has anybody run Kano OS in an emulator?** Is it possible?

Comment: Your commandline explicitly emulates an older CPU than Kano supports . Try settting the CPU to cortex-a9 .

Comment: @flakeshake With `-cpu cortex-a9` I get:

 `Uncompressing Linux... done, booting the kernel.


Error: unrecognized/unsupported processor variant (0x410fc090).`

Comment: @nachtigall Did you ever work out how to get this working? I've just set about trying to do the same thing.

Comment: @RajParmar No. I eventually gave up (but it's almost two years ago now). I do not think it is possible as there is probably no interest in it from Kano.

Answer (score 2):

Yes and no. It is not possible to run the official kano IMG in Qemu but you can run Raspbian and add the kano repositories to the `sources.list` file.

Install Raspbian Jessie on Qemu (This is for windows, just remove the .exe and stuff):
[Do this](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/118845/127045)

Add this to `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/kano.list`:

```
deb http://repo.kano.me/archive-jessie/ release main
deb http://repo.kano.me/archive-jessie/ release-urgent main
```

Run this to get the gpg:

```
wget -qO - http://repo.kano.me/archive-jessie/repo.gpg.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install kano-os #Which will install everything preinstalled on kano
```

You won't get the 'white rabbit' setup or anything, but on the next reboot, you will very likely get a kano desktop!