# Can't Emulate Raspbian Jessie on QEMU 2.1.2 (Debian)

Tags: raspbian, qemu

After following several guides which all pretty much say the same thing, I wind up with a kernel-qemu file and an unzipped, expanded disk image, and a command line (all grabbed from links on [this page](http://www.pcsteps.com/1199-raspberry-pi-emulation-for-windows-qemu/#Configure_the_Raspberry_Pi_emulation_for_QEMU)):

```
qemu-system-arm.exe -kernel kernel-qemu -cpu arm1176 -m 256 -M versatilepb 
     -no-reboot -serial stdio 
     -append "root=/dev/sda2 panic=1 rootfstype=ext4 rw init=/bin/bash" 
     -hda 2015-02-16-raspbian-wheezy.img
```

(I added some line breaks for readability; the command is all one line)

What happens is......nothing!  Well, not quite nothing: A QEMU window appears, all black.  I get some console messages about failures regarding pulseaudio, and after a very long wait during which one core of my host CPU is at 100%, the QEMU window vanishes and the following appears in the console:

```
qemu: hardware error: smc91c111_write: Bad reg 0:8
CPU #0:
R00=00000000 R01=00000183 R02=00000100 R03=00000000
R04=00000000 R05=00000000 R06=000001b8 R07=61000000
R08=10010008 R09=00000000 R10=00000000 R11=00000000
R12=00000000 R13=00000000 R14=00010050 R15=00010000
PSR=600001db -ZC- A und32
s00=00000000 s01=00000000 d00=0000000000000000
s02=00000000 s03=00000000 d01=0000000000000000
s04=00000000 s05=00000000 d02=0000000000000000
s06=00000000 s07=00000000 d03=0000000000000000
s08=00000000 s09=00000000 d04=0000000000000000
s10=00000000 s11=00000000 d05=0000000000000000
s12=00000000 s13=00000000 d06=0000000000000000
s14=00000000 s15=00000000 d07=0000000000000000
s16=00000000 s17=00000000 d08=0000000000000000
s18=00000000 s19=00000000 d09=0000000000000000
s20=00000000 s21=00000000 d10=0000000000000000
s22=00000000 s23=00000000 d11=0000000000000000
s24=00000000 s25=00000000 d12=0000000000000000
s26=00000000 s27=00000000 d13=0000000000000000
s28=00000000 s29=00000000 d14=0000000000000000
s30=00000000 s31=00000000 d15=0000000000000000
FPSCR: 00000000
Aborted
```

Some googling for "smc91c111_write bad reg" has yet to turn up anything useful.  Has anyone else encountered this or have a solution?

Addendum: I found [this related StackExchange article](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/38009/cannot-emulate-raspberry-pi-using-qemu-kernel-panic) and noticed the `-nographic` argument; tried adding that and the only effect was to prevent the blank window from appearing; otherwise the result was the same.