# Is it possible to get the state of the LEDs and GPIOs in a QEMU emulation like the HDMI and audio?

Tags: qemu, bare-metal

I've gotten QEMU emulation working with: [Emulation on a Linux PC](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/165/emulation-on-a-linux-pc)

On that Linux based example, I can see the HDMI output on a window, and hear sounds from the speaker.

Now I started playing with bare metal, and the hello world is to blink the OK LED.

Is it possible to get the value of the OK LED from QEMU somehow, without modifying my bare metal code at all?

Same goes for the on / off state of the GPIO pins.

Comment: You need to share the code for us to be able to tell you

Comment: @MohammadAli http://stackoverflow.com/a/40063032/895245 but why is it relevant? Shouldn't the emulation be determined by the hardware spec alone?

Answer (score 1):

**GPIO**

I think it is not possible, but I've found the QEMU 2.7.0 callback that gets called when you do GPIO:

```
hw/gpio/pl061.c:pl061_write
```

where PL061 is the GPIO controller of `-M versatilepb` (edit: `-M raspi2` was added in QEMU 2.6, see that instead) which is [documented here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/topic/com.arm.doc.ddi0190b/DDI0190.pdf).

This is the [setup I'm using to test it out](https://github.com/cirosantilli/linux-kernel-module-cheat/blob/8823f45d402f157ed194755473dfd3b9d6fdb4fb/rootfs_overlay/gpio.sh).

You could then monitor GPIO changes by printing to a file:

```
s->parent_obj->mmio[0].addr
```

which contains the MMIO base addresses, e.g. `0x101e7000` as in:

```
/sys/devices/platform/amba/101e7000.gpio/gpio/gpiochip480
```

and the offsets within each controller can be obtained with `offset`.

You could also compile with:

```
./configure --extra-cflags=-DDEBUG_PL061=1
```

which prints some interesting `PL061` debug information.

The `hw/arm/versatilepb.c` QEMU file sets up 4 such controllers, each one capable of dealing with 8 pins

The MMIO address of those controllers is given by the `.dts` device tree file, which is generated with the Linux kernel build from `versatile-pb.dts`.

I'm not sure how the exported IDs (e.g. `480`) are chosen for the pins by the Linux kernel.

Linux has in-tree support for the PL061 under `drivers/gpio/gpio-pl061.c`, which my test script accesses througg `/sys/class/gpio`.

**LEDs**

Add a `printf` at `hw/misc/arm_sysctl.c`:

```
static void arm_sysctl_write(void *opaque, hwaddr offset,
                            uint64_t val, unsigned size)
{
    arm_sysctl_state *s = (arm_sysctl_state *)opaque;

    switch (offset) {
    case 0x08: /* LED */
        printf("LED val = %llx\n", (unsigned long long)val);
```

The kernel driver is `drivers/leds/leds-syscon.c`.

Comment: Any reason for still using board "versatilepb" instead of "raspi2" or similiar ??

Comment: @flakeshake I think because I was previously using QEMU 2.0.0 from Ubuntu 14.04 which didn't have raspi yet, and I didn't know it was added. Thanks for the info.